# How to read and write data from mysql to JSON and then use for google table chart

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have employee table in mysql database
Table columns as..
empno
ename
sal...etc
I am creating custom query page..where user will type there query in textarea and then click on submit button..I want to retrive data from mysql according to user requested column and want to show google chart table.

I tried through JSON but no luck

Following code is what i did...

```
<form action="fire.php" id="usrform" method="post" target="iframe1">
    <p> Enter custom query here...</p>
    <textarea name="query" form="usrform" wrap="hard soft" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>                   <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Fire Query">
</form>
```

Fire .php page...

```
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass) or die ("could not connect to mysql");

mysqli_select_db($con,$db_name) or die ("no database");  
//query all records from the database
$query=$_POST['query'];
$returnArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))    
{    
$returnArray[] = $rs;     
}
$fp = fopen('sampledata.json', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($returnArray));
fclose($fp);
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
              var jsonData = $.ajax({
                  url: "getdata.php",
                  dataType:"json",
                  async: false
                  }).responseText;

              // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

              // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
              var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data, {width: 700, height: 400});
            }
            </script>
             <div id="chart_div"></div>
             </html>
```

getdata.php

```
<?php 
$string = file_get_contents("sampledata.json")`enter code here`;
echo $string;
?>
```

Please advise on this as I am not getting table chart

Answer (score 0):

Try and change

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "getdata.php",
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;
```

In to something like

```
var jsonData;
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "getdata.php",
  dataType:"json",
  async: false,
  type: "GET"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  jsonData = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 700, height: 400});
});
```

and it would be suggested to add a function to call the charts maybe with a json data parameter.